# Error in J2me code,Related to Memory,Performance

Tags: java, java-me

```
13068727 byte-codes executed
1886 thread switches
1682 classes in the system (including system classes)
22937 dynamic objects allocated (2043812 bytes)
86 garbage collections (1917296 bytes collected)
```

It is also giving out of memory error, `byte-code exceeded maximum limit 32byte-code`

These error message are generated while I run my project.

Answer (score 0):

> 13068727 byte-codes executed 1886 thread switches 1682 classes in the system (including system classes) 22937 dynamic objects allocated (2043812 bytes) 86 garbage collections (1917296 bytes collected)

These are not error messages.  They are merely informational - telling you about the performance of your device / application.

> It is also giving out of memory error ,byte-code exceeded maximum limit 32byte-code

That looks a bit strange.  It might be saying that your program is too large for the device, but it is hard to tell because you have (obviously!) not transcribed it accurately.  If you want a proper diagnosis, please cut-and-paste the **precise** error messages and any stack traces into the Question.

---

I think that the "Maximum byte code length exceeded (32kb)" message means that you have a class or method that is too big.  If you have a class or method called "Elements" that is the most likely culprit.  It is also possible that an instance is too big ...

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Elements: Maximum byte code length (32kB) exceeded 
this is the exact message